# Probability of positive inner product with expectation of one variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

Assume that $\mathbb{P}(X\cdot Y > 0) > 0$ and $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$. Can we say that $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}[X]\cdot Y > 0) > 0$?

Edit: Also assume that $\mathbb{P}(X\cdot Y \ge 0) = 1$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robert points out, $X=Y$ and $E[X]=0$ gives a counterexample. If $E[X]\neq 0$, here is another counterexample:

Let $(X,Y)$ take values $(-1,-2), (0,-1), (2,0)$, each with probability $1/3.$

Note $$E[X]=1/3,P(XY>0)=P(X=-1,Y=-2)=1/3, P(XY\geq 0)=1$$ but
$$P(E[X]Y>0)=P(Y>0)=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X$, $Y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X=-5) = \frac{1}{2}$, $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, $Y>0$.

Then $\frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(X\cdot Y>0)  > 0$, $\mathbb{E}[X] = -2 <\infty$ but $\mathbb{P}\left(\mathbb{E}[X]\cdot Y> 0\right) =\mathbb{P}\left(Y<0\right) =0 $.

Edit: In case your condition is $\mathbb{E}|X| <\infty $ instead of $\mathbb{E}[X] <\infty $ (I don't know it that's a typo) the example still stands.

Comment: Thank you. What if we know that $\mathbb{P}(X\cdot Y \ge 0) = 1$?

Comment: Not quite.  You could have $\mathbb E[X] = 0$ with $Y=X$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael can you think of more counterexamples? I am starting to get convinced that it holds if, for example, $\mathbb{E}[X] \neq 0$.

Comment: @Yuumita See my response for another counterexample.